# Speed up large string data parser function

Tags: vb.net

I currently have a file with 1 million characters.. the file is 1 MB in size. I am trying to parse data with this old function that still works but very slow.

```
start0end
start1end
start2end
start3end
start4end
start5end
start6end
```

the code, takes about 5 painful minutes to process the whole data.
any pointers and suggestions are appreciated.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sFinal = ""
    Dim strData = textbox.Text
    Dim strFirst = "start"
    Dim strSec = "end"

    Dim strID As String, Pos1 As Long, Pos2 As Long, strCur As String = ""

    Do While InStr(strData, strFirst) > 0
        Pos1 = InStr(strData, strFirst)
        strID = Mid(strData, Pos1 + Len(strFirst))
        Pos2 = InStr(strID, strSec)

        If Pos2 > 0 Then
            strID = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(strID, Pos2 - 1)
        End If

        If strID <> strCur Then
            strCur = strID

            sFinal += strID & ","
        End If

        strData = Mid(strData, Pos1 + Len(strFirst) + 3 + Len(strID))
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like a question for [codereview.se] 

Comment: Did you forget to ask your question or is this just one of those... "fix my code for me" type questions? Try to figure out why it's slow for yourself (a rather fun exercise) and then come back when you have a specific question about how to fix it.

Comment: I am not asking for someone to fix it but to give me a few pointers..

Comment: pointer 1: If it is a FILE with LINES, try treating it that way rather than a 1MB string. 2: remember string are immutable. 3: If you want to ignore #2, try inserting the ',' rather than hacking up the string 2 or 3 times per pass.

Comment: And 4: Post this on Code Review, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that is so slow is because you keep destroying and recreating a 1 MB string over and over.  Strings are immutable, so `strData = Mid(strData...` creates a new string and copies the remaining of the 1 MB string data to a new `strData` variable over and over and over.  Interestingly, even VB6 allowed for a progressive index.

I would have processed the disk file LINE BY LINE and plucked out the info as it was read  (see `streamreader.ReadLine`) to avoid working with a 1MB string.  Pretty much the same method could be used there.

```
' 1 MB textbox data (!?)
Dim sData As String = TextBox1.Text
' start/stop - probably fake
Dim sStart As String = "start"
Dim sStop As String = "end"

' result
Dim sbResult As New StringBuilder
' progressive index
Dim nNDX As Integer = 0

' shortcut at least as far as typing and readability
Dim MagicNumber As Integer = sStart.Length
' NEXT index of start/stop after nNDX
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim j As Integer = 0

' loop as long as string remains 
 Do While (nNDX < sData.Length) AndAlso (i >= 0)
    i = sData.IndexOf(sStart, nNDX)             ' start index
    j = sData.IndexOf(sStop, i)                 ' stop index

    ' Extract and append bracketed substring 
    sbResult.Append(sData.Substring(i + MagicNumber, j - (i + MagicNumber)))
    ' add a cute comma
    sbResult.Append(",")

    nNDX = j                               ' where we start next time
    i = sData.IndexOf(sStart, nNDX)
 Loop

 ' remove last comma
 sbResult.Remove(sbResult.ToString.Length - 1, 1)

 ' show my work
 Console.WriteLine(sbResult.ToString)
```

EDIT: Small mod for the ad hoc test data

Comment: thanks for taking the time to comment on this questions.. when I run your code I get an error on this line j = sData.IndexOf(sStop, i) saying 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

Comment: it works with the same yes, but for some reason it wont with this start hello end
start sup end

Comment: I think the issue is that I am using  Dim sData As String = RichTextBox1.Text and when changed to TextBox1.Text it works.. pretty weird..

Comment: cus I cant paste the 1MB data in the regular textbox so thats why Im using the RichTextBox what causing this ?

Comment: I have to ask WHY 1MB of data is in a textbox...if it was read from file into a string, pass and parse that.  it does not have to be SEEN to be processed.  Made a mod to look ahead for the end of the line -  see the edit.

Comment: your code its extremely fast and it works.. I am using this to parse data from html files too and if somehow there are two name in the same line that I need to extract it only extracts one.. any way around that?

Comment: how fast? you said the old way was 5mins/1MB, what is this (approx).  It isnt really the code (ie NET string ops vs VB), but not trashing the 1MB string 1-2 times per  test.  She also got rid of all the IF tests...

Comment: took about Milli:86.7419 for a 1MB File

Comment: LOL 3448% ?  `strData = Mid(strData...` was causing VB to COPY HUGE chunks of string data to the new variable...just start looking for the next bracket further on instead of chopping off the processed part.  not sure why it would skip a repeat...but I dont really know what the data looks like

Comment: amazing huh, thanks a lot for all the help.. I accepted the answer!