# Handling Lots of Optional Parameters

Tags: vb.net, function, optional-parameters

I'm embarrassed to share this function, but I need help uncluttering it. I wrote this a long time ago for a very simple use, but it's grown out of control and I'm not sure how to properly handle it.

```
Public Shared Function SetVariables(msg As String, Optional name As String = "", Optional target As String = "", Optional amount As Decimal = 0, Optional cost As String = "0", Optional keyword As String = "", Optional time As String = "", Optional reward As String = "", Optional participantList As String = "", Optional participantCount As Integer = 0, Optional game As String = "", Optional viewers As String = "", Optional followers As String = "", Optional link As String = "", Optional _options As String = "", Optional Year As String = "", Optional Month As String = "", Optional Day As String = "", Optional Hour As String = "", Optional Minute As String = "", Optional grpname As String = "")
    Dim balance As Decimal
    Dim holdings As Decimal
    If name > "" Then
        If Options.Accounts.ContainsKey(name) Then
            If Options.Holdings.ContainsKey(Options.Accounts.Item(name)) Then
                holdings = Options.Holdings.Item(Options.Accounts.Item(name))
            End If
            balance = Options.Accounts.Item(name).Points
        End If
    End If
    msg = msg.Replace("[name]", StrConv(name, VbStrConv.ProperCase))
    If holdings > 0 Then
        msg = msg.Replace("[balance]", balance & "[" & holdings & "]")
    Else
        msg = msg.Replace("[balance]", balance)
    End If
    msg = msg.Replace("[channel]", Subs.UppercaseFirstLetter(Options.Channel.TrimStart("#")))
    msg = msg.Replace("[target]", Subs.UppercaseFirstLetter(target))
    msg = msg.Replace("[amount]", amount)
    msg = msg.Replace("[cost]", cost)
    msg = msg.Replace("[keyword]", keyword)
    msg = msg.Replace("[time]", time)
    msg = msg.Replace("[reward]", reward)
    msg = msg.Replace("[participantList]", participantList)
    msg = msg.Replace("[participantCount]", participantCount)
    msg = msg.Replace("[botname]", Subs.UppercaseFirstLetter(Options.User))
    If msg.Contains("[groups]") Then msg = msg.Replace("[groups]", GetSortedGroups(name))
    If msg.Contains("[group]") Then msg = msg.Replace("[group]", GetSortedGroups(name, True))
    msg = msg.Replace("[game]", StrConv(game, VbStrConv.ProperCase))
    msg = msg.Replace("[viewers]", viewers)
    msg = msg.Replace("[followers]", followers)
    msg = msg.Replace("[link]", link)
    msg = msg.Replace("[options]", options.ToUpper)
    msg = msg.Replace("[years]", Year)
    msg = msg.Replace("[months]", Month)
    msg = msg.Replace("[days]", Day)
    msg = msg.Replace("[hours]", Hour)
    msg = msg.Replace("[minutes]", Minute)
    msg = msg.Replace("[grpname]", StrConv(grpname, VbStrConv.ProperCase))

    If balance = 1 Or amount = 1 Then
        msg = msg.Replace("[currency]", Options.PName)
    Else
        msg = msg.Replace("[currency]", Options.PNames)
    End If
    Return msg
End Function
```

Basically I pass a string to this function, it contains a few of these: [name] [keyword], etc, to be replaced with something else. Sometimes I have to also pass the data to replace those with too, that's where the problem starts. I wanted these in the same function, but I have way to many parameters now. I never use all of these parameters in a single call of the function and I'm going to be adding a ton more as time goes on.

Any advice on how to better handle something like this? Should I just tear this function apart and handle the replacements on an individual basis?

Comment: A class made up of those params should make it more concise

Comment: You may be right. I actually thought about doing this awhile back and forgot about the idea. Thanks!

Comment: @Plutonix Using what I shared in my OP are you able to write a rough example of how you would structure this class? It still feels like I'm going to have a really long string when using this class, but maybe I'm looking at wrong.

Comment: Well, if it was *my code* iI use a class and that procedure would be a method in it.  If at all possible, rather than hacking that `msg` string to bits, and I'd use StringBuilder to construct it.  I dont know what some of those other methods do though.

Comment: ...It sounds like you constructed the string passed to it, so rather than placeholders (`[Name]`), I'd try to build it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing that is pretty expensive.  `Strings` are immutable, so a line like this:

```
msg = msg.Replace("[followers]", followers)
```

...tears apart the original `msg` then creates a new one from the pieces and the replacement.  I've done the exact thing you are with short strings the user creates to specify the layout of a text block, but `StringBuilder` will be faster and more efficient on longer string and/or lots of replacements.  [This post is an extreme example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19441483) using a 1MB string (SB chopped the time from 5 min to 86 milliseconds).

Since it sounds like you constructed the starting string being chopped up, if at all possible I'd try to construct it from scratch and format it along the way.  I dont know enough about the data or some of the other methods, but this should give you an idea:

```
Public Class MessageMaker
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Target As String
    Public Property Amount As Nullable(Of Decimal)
    Public Property Cost As String          ' string? Really?

    ' illustration
    Public Property Participants As List(Of String)
    ' ergo participantCount==Participants.COunt()

    Public Property GroupName As String
    ' etc ad nauseum

    Public Sub New()
        Participants = New List(Of String)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetFormattedMsg() As String
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder

        sb.AppendFormat("The Name: {0}; ", Name)
        ' or...this will only append the name when lengh>0
        'sb.AppendFormat(If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name), "", TitleCase(Name) & "; "))

        If Amount.HasValue Then
            sb.AppendFormat("amt = {0}; ", Amount.Value.ToString("C2"))
        End If

        Dim p As String = ""
        If Participants.Count > 0 Then
            sb.AppendFormat("Participant Count: {0}; ", Participants.Count)
            ' convert names to TitleCase, sort
            p = String.Join(", ", Participants.OrderBy(Function(x) x).
                             Select(Function(j) TitleCase(j)))

            sb.AppendFormat("Participant Names: {0}; ", p)
        End If

        sb.Append(If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(GroupName), "",
                                   String.Format("Grp: {0}; ", TitleCase(GroupName))))

        Return sb.ToString

    End Function

    Private Function TitleCase(str As String) As String
        Return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower)
    End Function

End Class
```

Note that the `Amount` is `Nullable(Of Decimal)` (or could be written `As Decimal?`).  If you wanted to  omit it unless it was given, you could use `.HasValue` to determine that.  This can prevent misleading numbers: does `Amount: 0` really mean 0 or does it mean it wasnt specified.  Dont bother with `Nullable<T>` unless that matters.

The `GroupName` handling shows how to conditionally add text.  I also replaced the old fashioned `StrConv` to a NET method.  I dont know what `GetSortedGroups` does but any group list could be sorted on the fly if you wanted (as shown for `Participants`).

Depending on what else this class needs to do, rather than the method, that result could come from `.ToString()`:

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    ' all the code
    Return msg
End Function
```

Test Code:

```
Dim mm As New MessageMaker
mm.Name = "April Gala Festival"
mm.Amount = 1.23D
mm.Participants = New List(Of String) From {"ziggy", "zOEy", "HOOveR", "josh"}

Dim msg = mm.GetFormattedMsg()
' or
Dim msg = mm.ToString()
```

Result:

> "The Name: April Gala Festival; amt = $1.23; Participant Count: 4; Participant Names: Hoover, Josh, Ziggy, Zoey; "

I am guessing the resulting string has some titles and delimiters.  The method uses `"; "` after each segment or element.

Comment: I get it. I think I know what I need to do now. Unconditionally helpful as always. Thank you.